# How can i provide multiple Implementations for a React Context.Provider?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using nextjs with react

Domain: An Inputmanagement system where a document can be directly associated with an inbox, or a task. Depending on the configuration.

Problem statement:
Depending on a environment variable I want to provide different inboxes which depend on different providers:

```
//index.page.tsx
const InboxPage: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
    const {supportTasks} = useConfiguration()

    const taskInbox = () =>
        <InboxProvider>
            <TaskProvider>
                <DocumentsProvider>
                    <TaskInbox/>
                </DocumentsProvider>
            </TaskProvider>
        </InboxProvider>;

    const documentInbox = () =>
        <InboxProvider>
            <DocumentsProvider>
                <DocumentInbox/>
            </DocumentsProvider>
        </InboxProvider>;

    return (
        <>
            {supportTasks ? taskInbox() : documentInbox()}
        </>
    );
};
```

I want to have** two different implementations of the DocumentsProvider**, where a caller does not have to worry in which "confiugration" mode the system is currently running. A caller should always be able to call:
  `const { documents, setSelectedDocuments, selectedDocuments } = useDocuments();`
And receive the documents according to the implementations of the Provider (inboxDocument or taskDocument).

I tried to achieve this with the following generic useDocuments.tsx file where depending on the config the contextValue of the two available implementations should be injected:

```
//useDocuments.tsx
//imports omitted

export type DocumentContextProps = {
    //some methods and values
};

type Contexts = {
    inbox: DocumentContextProps;
    task: DocumentContextProps;
};

const DocumentsContext = React.createContext<DocumentContextProps | null>(null);

export const useDocuments = (): DocumentContextProps => {
    const documentsContext = useContext(DocumentsContext);
    if (!documentsContext) {
        throw new Error('useDocuments must be used within a DocumentsProvider');
    }
    return documentsContext;
};

const DocumentsProvider: React.FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren> = ({children}) => {
    const {supportTasks} = useConfiguration();
    const contexts: Contexts = {
        inbox: useContext(InboxDocumentsContext),
        task: useContext(TaskDocumentsContext),
    };

    const contextValue = supportTasks ? contexts.task : contexts.inbox;

    return <DocumentsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        {children}
    </DocumentsContext.Provider>;
};

export default DocumentsProvider;
```

The two implementations are:

```
// useInboxDocuments.tsx

export const TaskDocumentsContext = React.createContext<DocumentContextProps>(
    {
        //default values
    }
);

const TaskDocumentsProvider: React.FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {

   //providing business-logic

    return (<TaskDocumentsContext.Provider value={{
        //values
    }}>{children}</TaskDocumentsContext.Provider>)
};

export default TaskDocumentsProvider;
```

and:

```
//useTaskDocuments.tsx

export const TaskDocumentsContext = React.createContext<DocumentContextProps>(
    {
        //default values
    }
);

const TaskDocumentsProvider: React.FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {

    //providing business-logic


    return (<TaskDocumentsContext.Provider value={{
        // values
    }}>{children}</TaskDocumentsContext.Provider>)
};

export default TaskDocumentsProvider;
```

This implementation fails because the check in useDocuments (useDocuments.tsx) throws the error:
   `if (!documentsContext) { throw new Error('useDocuments must be used within a DocumentsProvider'); }`

**How can i achieve wrapping these two providers into one. Note that both providers implement the exact same methods.**